# grails scaffolding configuration by domainclass

Tags: grails, scaffolding

at the moment I try to deal with scaffolding in grails. There I have a little problem with the generation-templates where i don't find a solution. I want to configure the generating-algorithm in the domainmodel.
My thought was to define static variables in the model which aren't created in the database and only important for the generation-process.
For example I want to display only some special fields in the show.gsp but i want to display every field in the _form.gsp Or i want to do some gsp-imports but only in seperate gsp.
So i thought that i could define some static variables where the value contains some configuration-parameter i can interpretate in the generation template.
I hope everybody understand what I mean ?

Here is an example:

```
class Awesome {
Long awesome_level
Long person_name
    Boolean itsMe

static String showFields 
static transients = ['showFields']

static constraints = {
    einrichtungs_type()
    type_of_conzept()
    anzahl_gruppen()
    anzahl_kinder_pro_Gruppe()
    offnungszeiten()
    showFields(["person_name", "itsMe"])
}
```

In the Show-View i only want to display the fields in the array "showFields"

```
...
for (p in props) {
    if (p.embedded && p.name in domainClass.showFields) {
        def embeddedPropNames = p.component.persistentProperties*.name
        def embeddedProps = p.component.properties.findAll { embeddedPropNames.contains(it.name) && !excludedProps.contains(it.name) }
        Collections.sort(embeddedProps, comparator.constructors[0].newInstance([p.component] as Object[]))
        %><fieldset class="embedded"><legend><g:message code="${domainClass.propertyName}.${p.name}.label" default="${p.naturalName}" /></legend><%
            for (ep in p.component.properties) {
                renderFieldForProperty(ep, p.component, "${p.name}.")
            }
        %></fieldset><%

    } else {
        renderFieldForProperty(p, domainClass)
    }
...
```

I know that the if clause don't work. My problem is, that i am not able to get the value of the field "showFields".
Know my questions:

- Is it able to receive the values of a field of a domainclass?
- Is it able to execute a methode of a domainclass?
- Is there an other way do define configuration-parameters which i can access in the generation-templates?

I hope i was able to display my problem and thank you for some help!
Greetz
V

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that problem. First of all I thought it could be possible with the creation of a custom-Constraint. I am still thinking that this is also possible but i found a better /easyer way to add "configurations".
I use the tag attributes, which already exsits. If i understand it right, the attributes parameter i used to add attributes in select-Html-tags. Now i use it for adding some configuration-parameters. Here my solution:

1. You have to change the "renderEditor.template" that not all the configuration-parameter will add in a HTMl-tag as a attribute. `cp.attributes.each { k, v ->
               sb << "${k}=\"${v}\" "
           }` change to `cp.attributes?.realAttributes.each { k, v ->
               sb << "${k}=\"${v}\" "
           }`
2. When you realy want to this attributes-function add into the attributes-parameter the value "realAttributes" (or how you would like to call it)
3. Change the constraints of the model: (in my example:)

> static constraints = {        einrichtungs_type(attributes:
>   [showField:true])
>       }

1. Finaly change the generation-template

> if(cp.attributes?.showField){
>       ...

I hope these 4 steps help you, if you have nearly the same problems.

Greetz

V